# How to get all child elements of a STEP model and display them as a tree view using OpenCascade?

Tags: c++, linux, step, opencascade

The main purpose is to go through all child elements of a STEP model and to make a tree view out of them using OpenCascade. Now I am downloading the STEP model according to a particular path to a TopoDS_Shape object and then I am passing this object to the AIS_Shape object in order to finally display the model in the viewport. So, I thought that there was a method that should get a model path or a model itself as a parameter, then recursively go through all its child and finaly prints them somewhere

```
void OcctGtkViewer::onSTEPLoad(std::string filename)
{
  string tempFileName = "";

  STEPControl_Reader reader;
  TopoDS_Shape shape;

  if (filename == "")
     filename = tempFileName;

  const char *encodename = filename.c_str();
  if (reader.ReadFile(encodename) != IFSelect_RetDone)
  {
      cout << "Выбран не STEP файл!" << endl;
      return;
  }

  Standard_Integer nbr = reader.NbRootsForTransfer();

  for (Standard_Integer n = 1; n <= nbr; n++)
  {
      cout << "STEP: передаю корневой объект " << n << endl;
      reader.TransferRoot(n);
  }

  Standard_Integer nbs = reader.NbShapes();

  shape = reader.OneShape();
  STEPShape = reader.OneShape();

  cout << "STEP: файл загружен " << endl;

 //TDocStd_Document document("/home/kirill/Desktop/1.STEP");

//traverseDocument(document);

 return;
}

{
    // dummy shape for testing
    onSTEPLoad(pathToFile);

    // TopoDS_Shape aBox = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(100.0, 50.0, 90.0).Shape();
    Handle(AIS_Shape) aShape = new AIS_Shape(STEPShape);
    myContext->Display(aShape, AIS_Shaded, 0, false);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask this directly in the OpenCascade forum, because I am not sure if that library is that widely spread over SO. But what is your understanding of a child? Do you mean the faces, the edges, bodies? It is really dependent on the topology of the STEP file

Comment: The entire model could consist of some other child models. So, the door could consist of the door itself and of a door handle - the child